# Git are stashes removed after shutdown

Tags: git

I stashed all my files and shutdown (Windows PC). When I open the pc after 5 hours later, everything in stashs are deleted.

How can I recover my latest stash?

When I command this, `git stash list`, responses empty.

Comment: Did you execute it in the same repository as before? Stashes are not deleted on PC shutdown, so they should still be there.

Comment: No, git stashes are stored in the .git Folder on your harddrive. They are not temporary stored in ram. What command did you use to create the stash?

Comment: @A.R.C. I used webstorm to stash it(not shelve).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I didnt change repository. Only shutdown the pc and open it again. I know it must not be deleted.

Comment: @A.R.C. .git/refs/stash inside:  NULLNULLNULLNULLNULL.. wrtites.

Comment: What does git status say?

Comment: @matt is says 'nothing to commit, working tree clean', I think pc was broken when shutting down and somethings are deleted. I tried recovery programs. There is nothing about removed folders/files

Comment: What does `chkdsk` say?

Answer (score 1):

What `git stash` does is make commits.  These commits are not on any branch at all, but they are still commits.

Because they're on no branch, they are not recorded in any branch names either.  Instead, they are stored in `refs/stash` and the reflog for it.  However, [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748776/git-are-stashes-removed-after-shutdown#comment109224123_61748776):

> `.git/refs/stash` [contains only NUL characters]

indicates that the `refs/stash` reference has been corrupted by something outside Git's control.

At this point, you need to find any "lost" commits.  One of the ones that Git finds will be the crucial missing stash commit.  There are instructions for finding lost stashes at the end of [the `git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).  They are Unix-specific but should probably work in most Unix-alike shells (e.g., bash for Windows) provided the additional non-Git commands are installed:

> ```
> git fsck --unreachable |
> grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 |
> xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
> ```

If this finds particular hash IDs, save them somewhere (cut and paste them) and try:

```
git stash show <hash>
```

on each one until you find your stash.  You can then use the same raw hash ID with a `git stash apply` command, to apply it.

Note this is `git stash show`, where the five letter word *stash* comes right after `git`.  It is *not* `git show stash`, where the wrong word comes right after the word `git`.  (The problem here is that `git show stash` is a valid command, but is one that does nothing useful!)